# Load the same Fragment with different data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had a fragment called **DomaineDashboardFragment**, if it's the current fragment and I opened it with a different data in the bundle, it's not refreshed, it keeps the old data, Does anyone have an idea to resolve that ?
the fragment works fine, the problem is just when I change data.

Comment: Share some code.

Comment: It sounds you are setting the data when the Fragment is created. Instead of a bundle you might consider having the fragment obtain the data from the activity when the Fragment becomes visible instead (see Fragment.setUserVisibleHint()).

Comment: I get data from the bundle, so there's any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To everyone faces the same probleme, you can do this :

```
      DomaineDashboardFragment currentFragment = (DomaineDashboardFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("DomaineDashboardFragment");

                                                      if(currentFragment != null && currentFragment.isAdded())
                                                         ((MyApplication)getApplication()).removeFragment(MainActivity.this, currentFragment);

                                                    Handler h = new Handler();
                                                    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void run() {
                                                            DomaineDashboardFragment domaineDashboardFragment = new DomaineDashboardFragment();

                                                            domaineDashboardFragment.setArguments(b);

                                                            ((MyApplication)getApplication()).setUpFragment(MainActivity.this, domaineDashboardFragment, R.id.fragment_container);

                                                        }
                                                    }, 100);
```

remove fragment and then attach the new one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest Android Architecture components and create a ViewModel class. So, what you can do it, whenever you get data in bundle in `Fragment`, set the data to ViewModel and `notifyChange();`

Other than this, you must detach and attach the fragment again to get the new data.